# maximum recursion depth exceeded when using Django redirects

Tags: python, django

I'm experiencing this error where when I try to redirect a user to a webpage using Django, it showed me this error

`maximum recursion depth exceeded`

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

def redirect(request):
    response = redirect("https://google.com")
    return response
```

app's urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.redirect, name="donate-home"),
]
```

Project's urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('donate/', include("support.urls"))
]
```

Did I do something wrong? Did I not add something in settings.py?

I'm new to Django

Comment: `redirect` is an in-built function. You need to rename that

Comment: Since in the function, you are recursively calling the `redirect` function, it throws an error.

Comment: I only said it once doe in my views.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the function "redirect", you ovewrites the built-in function "redirect" In this case its behaving like a recusive function. You just have to change the name of your funnction and it sould be fixed ;)

Comment: I think you just saved me a lot of time and headaches. Thanks!